# What's the difference between 'M-x load-file' and 'M-x load-library' in emacs?

Tags: emacs

I tried to reload the ~/.emacs file, and it seems that both of the command works fine. Then, what's the difference between the two? For loading .emacs, what command do I have to use?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From [the manual](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Lisp-Libraries.html):

> M-x load-library differs from M-x
>   load-file in that it searches a
>   sequence of directories and tries
>   three file names in each directory.
>
> Suppose your argument is lib; the three names are lib.elc, lib.el, and lastly just lib. If lib.elc exists, it is by convention the result of compiling lib.el; it is better to load the compiled file, since it will load and run faster.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. To add to that, `load-library` recognizes things in your `load-path`. `load-file` recognized file names in the current directory.